# Are PWAs linkable to playstore

Tags: web, google-play, progressive-web-apps

Is it possible to link my pwa to the app store and can I install it from there too?

Comment: It says from this [forum](https://www.reddit.com/r/PWA/comments/7bk8yv/is_it_possible_to_get_your_pwa_listed_in_google/) that unless you make it as a hybrid app. If you go to https://pwabuilder.com there is an online wizard that create a hybrid app for both Android and iOS, plus give you the basics files you need to be a PWA. PWA Builder will also automatically submit your PWA to the Windows store for you. You will need to complete the registration for any of the stores of course. It only submits to the Windows store because they have made PWAs first class applications on Windows.

Comment: That means answer is no @jess

Comment: Unfortunately no.

Comment: @jess I guess found solution. Check out [TWAs](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/10/using-twa)

Comment: That's good, if it helps you with your problem.